# python using requests with valid hostname

Tags: python, python-2.7, download, python-requests

Trying to use requests to download a list of urls and catch the exception if it is a bad url. Here's my test code:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

#goodurl
url = "http://www.google.com"

#badurl with good host
#url = "http://www.google.com/thereisnothing.jpg"

#url with bad host
#url = "http://somethingpotato.com"    

print url
try:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    print "the url is good"
except ConnectionError,e:
    print e
    print "the url is bad"
```

The problem is if I pass in url = "http://www.google.com" everything works as it should and as expected since it is a good url.

```
http://www.google.com
the url is good
```

But if I pass in url = "http://www.google.com/thereisnothing.jpg"

I still get :

```
http://www.google.com/thereisnothing.jpg
the url is good
```

So its almost like its not even looking at anything after the "/"

just to see if the error checking is working at all I passed a bad hostname: #url = "http://somethingpotato.com"

Which kicked back the error message I expected:

```
http://somethingpotato.com
HTTPConnectionPool(host='somethingpotato.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1b6cd15b90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
the url is bad
```

What am I missing to make request capture a bad url not just a bad hostname?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

requests do not create a throwable exception at a 404 response. Instead you need to filter them out be checking to see if the status is 'ok' (HTTP response 200)

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

#goodurl
url = "http://www.google.com/nothing"

#badurl with good host
#url = "http://www.google.com/thereisnothing.jpg"

#url with bad host
#url = "http://somethingpotato.com"    

print url
try:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        print "the url is good"
    else:
        print "the url is bad"
except ConnectionError,e:
    print e
    print "the url is bad"
```

EDIT:
import requests
    from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

```
def printFailedUrl(url, response):
    if isinstance(response, ConnectionError):
        print "The url " + url + " failed to connect with the exception " + str(response)
    else:
        print "The url " + url + " produced the failed response code " + str(response.status_code)

def testUrl(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            print "the url is good"
        else:
            printFailedUrl(url, r)
    except ConnectionError,e:
        printFailedUrl(url, e)

def main():
    testUrl("http://www.google.com") #'Good' Url 
    testUrl("http://www.google.com/doesnotexist.jpg") #'Bad' Url with 404 response
    testUrl("http://sdjgb") #'Bad' url with inaccessable url

main()
```

In this case one function can handle both getting an exception or a request response passed into it. This way you can have separate responses for if the url returns some non 'good' (non-200) response vs an unusable url which throws an exception. Hope this has the information you need in it.

Comment: I was hoping to pass in the actually error (e) since I want to write the error to a file. Perhaps instead of printing "url is bad" in the else statement I can print r.status_code (which should be bad if it made to the else statement). Would you suggest that?

Comment: @chowpay The issue is that it is not actually an error so you wont be able to catch an error to print. I would suggest making a custom function to print out an "error" url which could include the url and the status code. If you would like an example I could add to my answer

Comment: @chowpay see if the code I added at the bottom does what you need

Comment: @chowpay No problem!

Comment: question, for  "isinstance(response,ConnectionError)" since you're feeding the function url and a response. how does "isinstance"  know that your "response" is a status code error vs a ConnectionError?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148559/discussion-between-skagra-dragneel-and-chowpay).

Answer (score 0):

what you want is to check `r.status_code`. Getting `r.status_code` on "http://www.google.com/thereisnothing.jpg" will give you 404. you can put a condition for only 200 code URL to be "good".